# Converter string para WE8MSWIN1252

Tags: php, oracle, encode

Começando trabalhar com PHP+Oracle, e estou com problemas para encodar as strings no formato WE8MSWIN1252 para oracle.

Alguém tem mais informações?

Comment: Que tipo de problemas?

Comment: Não achei como encodar, e o formato que achei "ISO-8859-1" não resolve

Answer (score 1):

Salvo algumas pequenas diferenças WE8MSWIN1252 é equivalente a ISO-8859-1 desta forma se você usa UTF-8 nas suas páginas PHP você deve procurar uma função que converta as Strings de UTF-8 para WE8MSWIN1252 e outra que faça o contrario. Desta forma você poderá converter os dados tipo String antes de persistir no Oracle e também após ler do Oracle.

**Da WEB para o database**

```
$utf8 = 'ÁÉÍÓÚÇÃÕ'; // o arquivo HTML / PHP deve estar codificado em UTF-8
$db_iso88591 = utf8_decode($utf8);
```

**Do Database para a WEB**

```
$db_iso88591 = 'ÁÉÍÓÚÇÃÕ'; // dado veio do database em ISO-8859-1 compativel
$utf8 = utf8_encode($db_iso88591);
```